# Does Java JDK have a GUI based program like Visual Basics or Android Studio?

Tags: java, user-interface, interface, javac

So I was learning Java with command prompt to compile my x.java file, but now I use Android Studio to use java to make apps. Is there a program like Android Studio or Visual Basics program where you write and test your java code?

Comment: Go to https://netbeans.org/downloads/ , choose Java EE column, then download it: It is what you're looking for.

Comment: Programs like that are called IDEs (Integrated Development Environments). There are many IDEs available for Java, e.g. see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Java_IDEs. The most common IDEs are: [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/), [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). Don't ask which is best, unless you're ready for a religious war.

Comment: According to [this article](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-tools-and-technologies-landscape-for-2014/6/) from 2014, Eclipse is the most commonly used IDE. However, Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA, so if you already know Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA should feel familiar to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys, yes I was looking for an IDE. I will be starting with Netbeans as it seems like the most common to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for an IDE. Such as Netbeans.